# Delete Files If value does Not exist

Tags: vba, excel

I'm searching for a clean way in VBA to solve this:

I have an Excel sheet containing value's in 1 row.
If the value's are found in a specified directory then they should be kept and all the others deleted.

A short example:

table:

```
     A
1   1000
2   1500
3   2000
4   1800
5   0009
```

Directory content on C:\Temp\1000.pdf ; 1200.pdf ; 1800.pdf ; 0001.pdf

So the action should keep 1000.pdf  and 1800.pdf and delete all other *.pdf 's

This is what I attempted yet, but this is just with one cell.

```
Dim cName As String

cName = Sheets("Blad2").Range("A2").Text

If Len(Dir("C:\Temp\" & cName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
Kill "C:\Temp\" & cName & ".pdf"
End If
```

Comment: [Please show us what you've attempted so far.](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this helps you:

```
Sub RemoveFiles()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim range As range
Dim found As range
Dim myFolder As String
Dim currFile As String
Dim currFileNoSuffix As String

Set sht = ActiveSheet
 ' Set the range to the A column-
 '   - only visible cells (xlCellTypeVisible)
 '   - and only constants, meaning skip over empty cells 
 '     and cells containing formulas or errors (7).
Set range = sht.range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible, 7)

' the files folder
myFolder = "C:\temp\111\"

' give me the first file in the folder
currFile = Dir(myFolder)

' while the code has not gone throug all of the files in the folder
While Not currFile = vbNullString
    ' put in the variable the name of the file without its suffix,
    ' for example 11111.pdf -->  will put 11111  into the variable.
    ' ! This does not change the the actual file in the directory!
    currFileNoSuffix$ = Mid(currFile, 1, InStrRev(currFile, ".") - 1)

    ' look for the name of the file in the "A" column.
    ' xlWhole means to search for an exact match, for example
    ' if you have a file named 111.pdf, it will only watch with a "111" sheet entry,
    ' but not with a "1111111" entry.
    Set found = range.Find(currFileNoSuffix$, , , xlWhole, , , False)

    ' if the filename does not appear in the sheet
    If found Is Nothing Then
        ' then delete the file
        Kill myFolder & currFile
    End If

    ' give me the next file in the folder
    currFile = Dir()
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I will use this one. Thanks for the clarification, makes it a lot easier for a noob like me ;)à

Answer (score 0):

To provide more context, this code loops through each cell in column A (save the top cell which it presumes is the header) and the feeds the Value of that cell to the function to be examined.
The function loops through every file in the provided folder (make sure you update the folder to match your own) and checks to see if file name is Like the criteria provided. (For more information about the Like Operator visit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Example()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim cll As Excel.Range
    Dim deletedCount As Long
    Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet
    Set rng = Excel.Intersect(ws.UsedRange.Offset(1&, 0&), ws.Columns(1), ws.UsedRange)
    For Each cll In rng.Cells
        deletedCount = deletedCount + DeleteFilesByCriteria("C:\_Test", cll.value & ".pdf", False)
    Next
    MsgBox "Deleted " & deletedCount, vbInformation
End Sub

Private Function DeleteFilesByCriteria(ByVal folderPath As String, ByVal criteria As String, Optional ByVal deleteReadOnly As Boolean = False) As Long
    'Create a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fldr As Scripting.Folder
    Dim fl As Scripting.File
    Dim deletedCount As Long
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)
    For Each fl In fldr.Files
        If fl.name Like criteria Then
            fl.Delete deleteReadOnly
            deletedCount = deletedCount + 1&
        End If
    Next
    DeleteFilesByCriteria = deletedCount
End Function
```

Comment: Your code looks solid but the answer as a whole would be massively improved by explaining how your code answers the question and providing a brief overview on how it works.

Comment: Did you make sure to set the reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime? (From the VBA Editor, go to Tools, then References and check "Microsoft Scripting Runtime.)